# Rails 6 gem client_side_validations applied to a model with context not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, client-side-validation

I have a model like this:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  validates :username, presence: true, on: :data_setup
end
```

where `:data_setup` is a page.

After installing the client side validation gem, it won't work, unless I erase the context part `on: :data_setup`

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: I believe you’re using `:on` incorrectly. Take a look here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectations for this are completely wrong. Models are not aware of the request, controller or anything else really outside the the model unless you explicitly pass it in or its a global.

For validations `on:` is most commonly used to restrict the validation to the `create` or `update` contexts. Note that this has nothing to do with what "page" you are on - the context is just tied to if the model instance is a new record or not.

When using custom contexts you need to manually trigger it by passing the context to `valid?`, `invalid?` or `save`:

```
Profile.new(username: nil).valid? # true
Profile.new(username: nil).valid?(:data_setup) # false
```